# Trigger que valide a porcentagem de cada rateio em uma nota de compra superior a x valor

Tags: trigger, oracle12c

Bom dia,
Estou com dificuldades em criar uma trigger que verificar no insert e no update um numero de rateio superior a x ( estou usando 30 para testes) em cada nota de compra. Essa é a primeira Trigger que crio em minha vida então não sei se o código que irei postar tem algo a ver. Trabalhamos com Oracle, existe uma tabela chamada TGFRAT onde armazena os valores de rateio da nota tendo NUFIN que seria o numero identificador da nota, PERCRAT é o percentual de rateio utilizado e que precisa ser validado, sendo que  o valor pode ser rateado em vários centros de custos, e ORIGEM que é um campo string que precisa receber 'E'. Preciso que a trigger valide se a soma de todos os rateios na nota seja superior a 30 , sendo que pode ser rateado em vários centros de custos. Desculpe caso a explicação tenha ficado difícil de entender, mas é por que realmente é a primeira vez que faço uma trigger. Desde já agradeço a atenção.

````
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TGFRAT  
FOR EACH ROW 
     DECLARE P_NUFIN       INTEGER;
            P_PERCRATEIO   FLOAT;
            P_ORIGEM      CHAR(1);
BEGIN 
    P_NUFIN =  NEW.NUFIN
    P_PERCRATEIO = NEW.PERCRATEIO
    P_ORIGEM = NEW.ORIGEM
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_PERCRATEIO  FROM TGFRAT WHERE NUFIN = P_NUFIN AND ORIGEM = P_ORIGEM;
IF
    (P_PERCATEIO >30) THEN ' ERROR'
END IF;

IF
    P_ORIGEM <> 'E' THEN ' ORIGEM ERROR'
END IF;
END ```
````

Comment: Não entendi estes seus `IF`. Você quer atribuir estas strings a algum campo?

Comment: Então, eu quero que ele valide se o ORIGEM está recebendo 'E' e se o PERCRATEIO é maior que 30. Como eu disse, eu nunca fiz uma Trigger, então fui olhando as que tem no banco pra servir de base.

Comment: 1) deveria ser sum(PERCRAT) no lugar de count(*) ,  creio eu. Mas mesmo assim creio que a trigger vai cair em "Mutating Table" que é um senhor complicador https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/mutating-table-error-in-oracle/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, amigo.Vou seguir o que me mandou